# How to get the distance between top of screen and layout which is a child

Tags: android

I am going to ask probably a basic question, but on the other hand I have searched over the internet and I couldn't find the proper solution for my problem.

I have implemented tic tac toe game, and when I put the winning 'x' or 'o' I want to draw crossing line through the winning set of signs. I could do it, but the position of this line is unwanted for me. I tried some params describing starting x,y and ending x,y but it didn't work.

This is example description of drawn line (I dont write the implementation of my own class, it just draws line with specified positions:)

```
 View tl = screen.findViewById(R.id.custom_board_table_row1);
            int x1 = tl.getLeft();
            int x2 = (tl.getTop()+tl.getBottom())/2;
            int x3 =tl.getRight();
            int x4 =(tl.getBottom()+tl.getTop())/2;
            wl = new DrawWiningLine(context,x1,x2,x3,x4,color);
```

(Not much enough reputation, so im pasting link to screen) https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5gkm.png

This drawn line should cross these 'X' but its above the tablelayout. I have found in the documentation that method such as getLeft() returns position of this view relative to its parent. I know that I should calculate the offset, but I have no idea how. I was thinking about getLocationOnScreen and getLocationInWindow, but I think it's not sufficient for me.

Could you help me and say how to do:
int offsetX = ...;

int offsetY = ...;

to make my code working?

Thanks in advice. I am pasting also xml file if it is not possible to help me without it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_board_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/custom_board_player1_text"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/custom_board_player2_text"
    />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom_board_table"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/custom_board_table_row1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <board.TrippleToggleButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <View style="@style/DividingVerticalLine"
                />
            <View style="@style/DividingHorizontalLine"
                android:id="@+id/custom_board_dividing_horizontal_1"/>

            <board.TrippleToggleButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <View style="@style/DividingVerticalLine"/>
            <board.TrippleToggleButton
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff000000">
            <View style="@style/DividingHorizontalLine"/>
         </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/custom_board_table_row2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <board.TrippleToggleButton
                />
            <View style="@style/DividingVerticalLine"/>
            <View style="@style/DividingHorizontalLine"/>
            <board.TrippleToggleButton
               />
            <View style="@style/DividingVerticalLine"/>
            <board.TrippleToggleButton
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff000000">
            <View style="@style/DividingHorizontalLine"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/custom_board_table_row3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <board.TrippleToggleButton
               />
            <View style="@style/DividingVerticalLine"/>
            <View style="@style/DividingHorizontalLine"/>
            <board.TrippleToggleButton
                />
            <View style="@style/DividingVerticalLine"/>
            <board.TrippleToggleButton
                />
        </TableRow>




    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/reset"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/custom_board_reset_button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layout

- To get vertical line position, set id for each board.TrippleToggleButton in row1

---

In code (not tested)

```
// t1.getLeft() and t1.getTop() returns 0 (with no margin or padding)

// if DrawWiningLine() base position is top left corner of custom_board_screen
View tableView = screen.findViewByID(custom_board_table);
int offsetX = tableView.getLeft();
int offsetY = tableView.getTop();

// horizontal line start pos (x1, x2), end pos (x3, x4)
// t1 position is relative to t1's parent(== custom_board_table) position
View tl = screen.findViewById(R.id.custom_board_table_row1);
int x1 = t1.getLeft() + offsetX;
int x3 = t1.getRight() + offsetX;
int x2 = t1.getTop() + t1.getHeight() / 2 + offsetY;
DrawWiningLine wl = new DrawWiningLine(context,x1,x2,x3,x2,color); // x4 == x2

// vertical line start pos (x1, x2), end pos (x3, x4)
View t3 = screen.findViewById(R.id.custom_board_table_row3); // get bottom from row3
View cellTop1 = screen.findViewByID(cell_top_left); // get left and right from cells
int x5 = cellTop1.getLeft() + cellTop1.getWidth() / 2 + offsetX;
int x6 = t1.getTop() + offsetY;
int x8 = t3.getBottom() + offsetY;
DrawWiningLine wl2 = new DrawWiningLine(context,x5,x6,x5,x8,color); // x7 == x5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with getLocation on screen

```
example : int coords[]={0,0};
view.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
int absoluteTop = coords[1];
int absoluteBottom= coords[1]+view.getHeight();

llly int absoluteLeft= coords[0];
int absoluteRight = coords[0]+view.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at View.getLocationOnScreen() and View.getLocationInWindow()

Comment: I have searched information about it, could you explain me more about it? View doesnt have this method, but if you mean main_layout.getLocationOnScreen() I dont know how to use it (tried to find some information on developer.android.com and similar posts but its totally unclear for me)

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow(int[]) and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[])